# Error while installing Laravel in docker #RUN groupadd --force -g sail

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-9

I am getting an error while installing Laravel in Docker.

I followed the instruction from https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation

```
Error:
CACHED [ 5/11] RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1                                                                                                                                      0.0s
ERROR [ 6/11] RUN groupadd --force -g  sail                                                                                                                                                               0.9s
> ------
6/11] RUN groupadd --force -g  sail:
> #0 0.835 groupadd: invalid group ID 'sail'
> ------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail]: exit code: 3
```

*your text*[image]

I am trying to install Laravel 9 in the docker but is facing error while installing it.

Taking 2 hours to complete this build

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the WWWGROUP env-variable in your host environment, so the docker container will not be able to map your host group to your container group.

add the following 2 variables to your .env file:

```
WWWGROUP=1000
WWWUSER=1000
```

(if you have other ids in your O/S), then replace `1000` with correct ID for the group and user you wish to use.

On ubuntu you can check this with following command:

`$ id [username]`

Comment: @Sabareesh You can accept my answer please, and post another question related to your new issues with the network connectivity for your docker container. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

When using sail you can just use:

```
sail up -d
```

After that the containers are created and started